# Unreal Engine 4 crahses

Tags: unreal-engine4

My Unreal Engine 4 keeps crashing [This is what its showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr8rb.png)
**EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION reading address 0x00000048**
This is the error I'm getting
If anyone could help me rectify it that would be great.
Cheers!

Comment: Try opening the log and see if it gives you anything else. Or look at the actual stacktrace, it usually points to where the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

This is the most common C++ error in Unreal Engine, and if you're writing code it's completely normal to see the engine crash if appeared one of the following errors:

- calling method or variable on a nullptr
- calling method or variable on a non-initialized pointer
- calling wrong methods in class constructor (you can't modify game states on the constructor)

If you're not writing c++ code try to verify the Engine's installation going in the launcher -> library -> engine -> versions, and click on you're installation and "verify".

Answer (score 0):

There is a very little information, when does this crash occurs? 
Are you using C++?

What I would suggest but it's a totally arbitrary guess (due to lack of information):

1. Check you are not using Nullptr
2. You create all the components in C++ on constructor
3. You are not using variables (except the components ones) on the constructor.
4. Related to point 1, Check if you were using a reference, it wasn't destroyed.

This is just a quite generic tips, if you can give more information maybe we'll find a more accurate solution.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try verifying the engine from the **Epic games launcher**

1. Open Epic games launcher
2. Go to the Unreal engine menu
3. Open library
4. Go to the engine versions
5. Click on the [icon right to the **launch** button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0O81.png)
6. Click on verify
7. Then wait for the engine to be verified

Hope it works